# Localstack Community Cloud Pods cli commands are not available

Tags: localstack

I’m following the guide on [Community Cloud Pods](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/cloud-pods/community/) using an Open Source tier to dump the localstack state into a pod and and the pods action just isn’t there - getting "Error: No such command 'pod'".

What I am missing?

```
➜  ✗ localstack --version
1.4.0
➜ ✗ localstack pod      
Usage: localstack [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'localstack --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'pod'.

➜ ✗ localstack --help
Usage: localstack [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  The LocalStack Command Line Interface (CLI)

Options:
  --version       Show the version and exit.
  --debug         Enable CLI debugging mode
  --profile TEXT  Set the configuration profile
  --help          Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  config  Inspect your LocalStack configuration
  infra   Manipulate LocalStack infrastructure (legacy)
  logs    Show the logs of the LocalStack container
  ssh     Obtain a shell in the running LocalStack container
  start   Start LocalStack
  status  Print status information about the LocalStack runtime
  stop    Stop the running LocalStack container
  update  Update LocalStack components
  wait    Wait on the LocalStack container to start
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing the same issue and I have a feeling that it's intentional and somehow a sneaky way to get you to upgrade to localstack pro :((